# Which of these two "for" statements are more efficient?

Tags: python, performance

Which of the following two codes are more efficient? (time & memory).

```
aList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for num in aList:
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        aList.pop(num)
```

or

```
aList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for num in range(10):
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        aList.pop(num)
```

So basiccaly what I'm asking is which of "for num in aList:" and "for num in range(10):" are more efficient ?

Comment: Neither of them works, so the question of performance doesn't even arise.

Comment: You should look into the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: A `tuple` and `pop`? Even if you change it to be a list, the first one won't run as you might expect it because you're modifying the list you're iterating over.

Comment: `aList = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` is not a list.

Comment: Even if using a list, the first version would modify a list while iterating it which is wrong. And the two versions don't do the same thing so comparing the efficiency is pointless.

Comment: Just edited the type of brackets.

Comment: `aList = range(10)` is just shorthand for `aList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Answer (score 1):

Even if your loop did work, `pop` is O(n) so makes your loop very inefficient. It's nearly always better to make a new filtered list and copy that back over

```
aList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
aList[:] = [n for n in aList if n % 2]
```